# Per-column Filter on ag-grid

Tags: filtering, ag-grid

How do I show per-column filters between the header label and data in ag-grid rather than having the filter in each column's dropdown menu?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best option on that would be to use the [Header Template](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/index.php) and include an input in there. You will also need to increase the height of the header inside of the gridOptions.

```
var gridOptions = {
    ...
    headerHeight: 150, // make this as tall as you need...
    headerCellTemplate: HEADER_CELL_TEMPLATE, // I chose to name template vars in all caps
    ...
}

var HEADER_CELL_TEMPLATE = '<div class="ag-header-cell">' + 
    '<div id="agResizeBar" class="ag-header-cell-resize"></div>' +
    '<span id="agMenu" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-cell-menu-button"></span>' +
    '<div id="agHeaderCellLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label">' +
        '<span id="agSortAsc" class="ag-header-icon ag-sort-ascending-icon"></span>' +
        '<span id="agSortDesc" class="ag-header-icon ag-sort-descending-icon"></span>' +
        '<span id="agNoSort" class="ag-header-icon ag-sort-none-icon"></span>' +
        '<span id="agFilter" class="ag-header-icon ag-filter-icon"></span>' +
        '<span id="agText" class="ag-header-cell-text"></span>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<input type="text" ></input>' +
'</div>'
```

Comment: i would have thought i missed some configuration parameter. this involves much more effort than adding an external search bar..

Answer (score 3):

There is also a [floatingFilter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/#gsc.tab=0) option for the grid config that does something close to this as well:

```
gridOptions = {
   // turn on floating filters
   floatingFilter: true
   ... 
}
```